# Find the file type

Tags: c#

How can I find the type of the file from the directory C#? I am reading the files from the directory and would like to find out if the file type is an image. Please let me know.

Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about this

```
string extension= System.IO.Path.GetExtension("s.jpeg");
   if ((extension == ".jpeg") || (extension == ".jpg") || (extension == ".bmp"))
   {
       //true
   }
   else
   {
       //false
   }
```

Answer (score 3):

If fileInf is of type IO.FileInfo

```
System.IO.Path.GetExtension(fileInf.FullName)
```

or

```
fileInf.Extension
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to determine the file type (presuming you dont just want to use the GetExtension() method) is to use [File Magic Numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_format#Magic_number), [here](http://www.daniweb.com/forums/thread210537.html#) and [here](http://www.astro.keele.ac.uk/oldusers/rno/Computing/File_magic.html).

[TrIDNet](http://mark0.net/soft-tridnet-e.html) has a great XML database of magic numbers.

Answer (score 0):

If you get the extension, there should be a way to look up the file type registered to that extension in Windows. I'm not sure how to do the latter off hand.